# Set sys_temp_dir in your php.ini

Tags: composer-php

PHP temp directory (C:\Program Files\KMSpico\temp;C:\xampp\php\tmp) does not exist or is not writable to Composer. Set sys_temp_dir in your php.ini

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for providing the error message and it is certainly clear that this error message creates some question marks. However it would be helpful if you add a bit more context. Which command did you run that produced the error? And do you know about the `composer diagnose` command? It checks and displays a couple of key data-points about your system configuration, which includes the PHP configuration (composer is running under). That can also shed additional details.

Answer (score 0):

On your system, the PHP function [`sys_get_temp_dir()`](https://www.php.net/sys_get_temp_dir) returns the string "`C:\Program Files\KMSpico\temp;C:\xampp\php\tmp`".

This is certainly a misconfiguration as it contains two pathnames concatenated with a semicolon ("`;`"):

1. `C:\Program Files\KMSpico\temp`
2. `C:\xampp\php\tmp`

The semicolon here is the *Windows Path Separator*. Composer does not support it, it expects a single pathname.

Check your PHP configuration, this can be controlled with the [`sys_temp_dir` setting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.sys-temp-dir).

Having multiple paths there-in looks like a misconfiguration to me, but I'm not using Windows much in the recent decades, so my knowledge is a bit rusty whether this is common or not. For me this really smells like some misconfiguration on your box.

In any case, having multiple paths is not a configuration that Composer supports. Hence you see the error message.

Have you tried to reset it to the default value (empty string)?

Have you recently fiddled with the TMP or TEMP environment parameter(s)?

Comment: i found the solution just went environment variables and removed the current path  (C:\Program Files\KMSpico\temp and replaced with  C:\xampp\php\tmp

Comment: @user17613159: Yes, that looks like you could solve it on the system level. The PHP ini setting allows you to control that on the PHP level. Then environment provides the default for the `sys_temp_dir` setting, which is why this works.

Comment: An create an answer out of your solution so that you have it documented as a way on how to handle the error. Please consider to do so.